# How to check if a variable is in specific range

Tags: python, list, range

I have a list of lists that looks like this:

```
 mylists =   [[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], 3.4207362518089726, 0.2808766238976195], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], 2.9687393162393163, 0.3408964829117446]]
```

What I am trying to do is to take a **number provided by the user** and then check if the number provided is equal or in a range of +0.6 compared to the second element of each sublist. In other words I want to do the following: if user input is 3.4 then I want to check based on the example provided of list of lists these two numbers: 3.4207362518089726 and 2.9687393162393163 and if these numbers are in range of +0.6 from the input, then to save the whole sublist in another list.

So, user_input = 3.4, mylists[0][1] = 3.4207362518089726, mylists[1][1] = 2.9687393162393163 and I want to place in a new list each sublist that has 3.4 **and above**, till 4.0 (due to range of **+ 0.6**)

What I thought was this:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylists)):
        if mylists[i][1] >= user_input + 0.6:
             new_list.append(mylists[i])
```

But of course this did not work.

Comment: So in the case of the user inputting 3.4, what would you want your new_list to finally look like?

Comment: It should have the first list only, meaning new_list = [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], 3.4207362518089726, 0.2808766238976195]]. Of course in case there were more lists with greater or equal then those lists should be added also here

Comment: so, while 3.42 fits your 3.4+0.6 criterion, 2.8 does not. Does that mean that the list of courses will be added to the output if the first number fits the criteria? or if either number fits the cretiria?

Comment: Effectively, I think you're looking for `mylists[i][1] <= user_input <= mylists[i][1]+0.6`

Comment: I am not sure if I get your question correctly, but if for example the 2.8 does not fit my cretiria then the whole sublist, the one that contains the 2.8 and its respective courses, should not be added to the new list. Only the sublist whose [1] fits my critiria should be added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your conditional is just written incorrectly - it is choosing sublists whose 2nd element is

`>= user_input + 0.6` (which evaluates to `>= 4.0`, but you want the 2nd element to be `between 3.4 and 4.0`. So I believe all you need to do is change it like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(mylists)):
    if user_input <= mylists[i][1] <= user_input + 0.6:
        new_list.append(mylists[i])
```

Hope that helps, happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

Are you getting an error or just an unexpected output?

perhaps you can try:

```
new_list = list(filter(lambda x: user_input<= x[1] <= user_input + 0.6 , mylists))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
import re

mylists =   [[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], 3.4207362518089726, 0.2808766238976195], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], 2.9687393162393163, 0.3408964829117446]]

user_input = 3.4

st = str(user_input) #transform input from user to string

denom = '1'+len(st.split('.')[-1])*'0' #get how much decimals st have and create denominator to the decimal part

decimal_part = 1- int(st.split('.')[-1])/int(denom) #create decimal numbers  to reach upper bound

new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(mylists)):
    if user_input <= mylists[i][1] <= user_input + decimal_part:
         new_list.append(mylists[i])
```

Another way is:

```
import numpy as np

mylists =   [[['CS105', 'ENG101', 'MATH101', 'GER'], 3.4207362518089726, 0.2808766238976195], [['CS105', 'ENG101', 'GER', 'GER'], 2.9687393162393163, 0.3408964829117446]]

user_input = 3.4

new_list = []

for i in range(0, len(mylists)):
    if user_input <= mylists[i][1] <= np.ceil(user_input):
         new_list.append(mylists[i])
```